# How to generate variables and then assigning an integer to them from a list (python3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
divisions = int(input('Divisions: '))
divisible = []

while divisions > 0:
    x = input('Divisble: ')
    divisible.append(x)
    divisions = divisions - 1
```

Trying to get the 'divisible' list to split into separate integer variables, but the problem i have is that the amount of variables that houses the integers changes. How would I solve this?

Comment: you want a list of ints from the first input statement?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: looks like OP is asking "how many divisions do you want to do?" and then collecting a list of that many ints. I have no idea what comes next

Comment: Doesn't look like you need many variables. Your one list holds multiple `int`s. What is this `split into separate variables` that you speak of? What are you trying to accomplish there? Would a list of lists not suffice?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: what I am aiming for is to be able to devise a number once by each number in the list. But I can't achieve this with the list since it has to be split into separate integers for the operators to work.

Comment: I'm still not sure I fully understand. Could you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: does  the list not have separate ints?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: right now, `divisible` contains a bunch of strings because of the way `input` is used in the while loop

Comment: are you inputting one at a time?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: right now, OP is inputting one string at a time, to append to `divisible`. However, what each string is interpreted as, is something that I do not know

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Say I have a value x=10. I want to devise x by each individual integer in the the list 'divisible'. I'm not sure if it would require the list to be separated into individual variables but each answer has to be a different variable.

Comment: @user3908466. is `x=10` actually x in your loop?

Comment: @user3908466: when you say "devise", do you mean "divide"?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: oh yes, english is not my best language.

Comment: I think some input and expected output would help

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: no, it is just an example. The actual numbers that need to be divided are also user generated in a loop.

Comment: Here is the challenge itself:

Your program should ask the user how many different divisible numbers to visualise, what they are, and how many beats to display. Each number corresponds to a column in the order that they were entered. For each beat, print out an X if the corresponding number divides the beat, with spaces in between for alignment. There should be no trailing whitespace on each line. Here is an example:

Divisions: 3
Divisible by: 2
Divisible by: 3
Divisible by: 4
Number of beats to print: 10
 1:
 2:X
 3: X
 4:X X
 5:
 6:XX
 7:
 8:X X
 9: X
10:X EDIT:Sorry about the formatting

Comment: @user3908466, I just meant does x actually represent the x variable  in your loop not the value

Comment: @user3908466: It would be far more helpful if you could post your comment as an edit to your question. Also, in your example, why does 6 have `XX` when it is not one of the divisibles?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the built-in reduce function

```
import functools

l = [2, 3, 4]
n = 24
result = functools.reduce(lambda a, v: a / v, l, n)

print('result: {}'.format(result))
```

This basically starts with n, divides, by 2, takes the answer and divides by 3, .. for each value in the list l, so the output is 1.

reduce was built in in python 2; now it's in the functools module.

[Here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import+functools%0D%0A%0D%0Al+%3D+%5B2,+3,+4%5D%0D%0An+%3D+24%0D%0A%0D%0Aprint('result%3A+%7B%7D'.format(functools.reduce(lambda+n,+v%3A+n+/+v,+l,+n)))&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=13)'s a link to see it running interactively at [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com)